# How do Italians customarily insert uppercase Italian vowels with diacritics with an Italian keyboard on a PC?

Tags: accents, letters, typography

How do Italians typically resolve the issue of entering uppercase vowels with diacritics on a PC (Windows or Linux) with an Italian keyboard, given that these are missing from the printed text appearing on the keys and by default cannot entered via `Shift` (also known on Italian keyboards as the `Maiusc` key), `Ctrl`, `Alt` key combinations (unless some modification is made to the default layout with the Microsoft MSKLC application)? On Windows 7 I have tried both the `Italiano` and the `Italiano (142)` keyboards and both lack this functionality by default. I cannot understand why those who created these keyboard layouts, however long ago that may be, never thought about adding key combinations for inserting uppercase Italian vowels with diacritics.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a simple solution for that. When using a word processor I usually type lower case and if needed (e.g. starting a new sentence) it's converted automatically. Otherwise you have to either copy/paste from character map or use ALT+xxxx combination (e.g. ALT + 0200 for È)

Comment: I use the `gvim` text editor to convert the character to uppercase once it's inserted by moving the cursor over the character and typing the `~` character with the keyboard configured as a US keyboard so that SHIFT + the key in the upepr-left hand corner yields the `~` character. However, this is only one solution. I doubt anyone else uses this method unless they come from a programming background. As for a full solution using ALT codes, see my answer below.

Comment: I cannot leave a comment as I only just joined specifically to help you out. This isn't an answer to your question but a solution to the problem. If there are common characters which you want to type (such as those missing accented capitals) you can use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) to customise your layout. For example I bought a US keyboard but I am British. So the keyboard was missing the £ sign. I added it back with this tool.

Comment: @Chro, yes, I was aware of that tool and in fact mentioned it in my question, but what I was looking for was the reason some of the characters often found in Italian text are missing from Italian PC keyboards. I in fact bought a computer with such a keyboard and this left me wondering about this issue. Regards.

Comment: I've just remapped my whole keyboard, but I guess I can be considered a quite advanced user.

Comment: There are some historical reasons why Italians don't really mind using apostrophes on capital letters and thus, they just do not customarily insert uppercase Italian vowels with diacritics. 1. We don't really have a large usage for diacritics or other "character accidents" therefore we don't get confused by replacing them in few, known, long tradition circumstances. To us, `E'` is almost a single letter (it means: "he/she/it is"), a concept not unknown to other cultures as well. See `LL` for Spanish. We have so few different diacritics and so few rules governing them, that people liberally mis

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but it is not an answer to the OP's question, and some of your points are questionable. In the first place, you can hardly tell English-speaking people that Italian has not a large usage for diacritics, when Italian has infinitely more so than almost-immune English: we have in everyday use at least six of them, even ignoring rarer circumflex accents, diaereses and so on. [to be followed]

Comment: In the second place, rounded letters and the like are not really a problem for sculptors (and a particularly elegant font, [Trajan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajan_(typeface)), is explicitly inspired by [such engravings](http://typophile.com/files/Trajaninscription_3854.jpg)), much less so accents, which are simple strokes, if anything more similar to the archaic  wedge-shaped characters of cuneiform. But this is actually uninteresting, since Latin did not us actual accents anyway.

Comment: Well, I think it is worth mentioning that although diacritics almost never appear in English words, the frequency of appearance of accent marks in Italian texts is less frequent than in French, but such accent marks are needed as it is not possile to write many Italian words correctly without them.

Comment: I have been using this keyboard layout for several years now: https://www.tastiera-aggiornata.it/index.htm?v=120

Answer (score 15):

Using the Italian keyboard layout on Linux (at least on Ubuntu 14.04), you can get the uppercase versions by engaging caps lock. For example, to type É, I turn on caps lock and press shift-è. I'm not sure whether this works on Windows and Mac, though.

In practice, I've noticed that Italians will often append an apostrophe in place of a grave accent when the diacritic is not available, or is too inconvenient to produce:

[image: E' VIETATO INTRODURRE cicli e motocicli]

Comment: No, caps lock is not being used as a compose key here: as your link says, a compose key "signals to the software to interpret the following keystrokes (usually two) as a combination to produce an alternate character". Toggling caps lock on the Linux Italian layout simply causes *all* letters to be capitalized; it won't let you explicitly compose a diacritic and a letter, and each letter (even with diacritics) only requires a single keypress. Caps lock works exactly as you'd hope: it gives you the capitalized version of what you're typing, even for letters like é which require shift to be held.

Comment: My previous comment was in reply to another comment which has since been deleted, but I'm leaving my reply in place since it provides some potentially useful clarification.

Comment: In any case, putting an apostrophe instead of a diacritic sign is actually an error.

Comment: The question asks how Italians customarily write capitals with diacritics, so I attempted to answer this particular question. I make no claims for the correctness of the custom which I report in my answer. The use of the apostrophe does seem to be common in practice even if not officially sanctioned, so I think it's a valid answer to the question as stated :-).

Comment: Well, this particular point can lead to a nearly infinite discussion, so I bet is better to stop here :).

Comment: So `È` is simply the sequence `caps lock` `è` `caps lock`! Wow, I've been using Linux for years now, and didn't know this one!

Answer (score 8):

On the PC, special Italian characters, many of which are not present on Italian keyboards, can be inserted using the following ALT codes. To use these, first ensure that the Num Lock key has been pressed once so that it has become enabled (this key is also known as the BI Num key on Italian keyboards); usually a green LED above the keyboard will light up once this key has been enabled. Next hold down the Alt key, type the four-digit numeric code, then release the Alt key. Here is the list:

```
À   ALT+0192 (Uppercase Stressed A)
È   ALT+0200 (Uppercase Stressed Open E)
É   ALT+0201 (Uppercase Stressed Closed E)
Ì   ALT+0204 (Uppercase Stressed I written with grave accent)
Í   ALT+0205 (Uppercase Stressed I written with acute accent)
Ò   ALT+0210 (Uppercase Stressed Open O)
Ó   ALT+0211 (Uppercase Stressed Closed O)
Ù   ALT+0217 (Uppercase Stressed U written with grave accent)
Ú   ALT+0218 (Uppercase Stressed U written with acute accent)   
Î   ALT+0206 (Uppercase (Ending Truncated Stressed) I with circumflex)

à   ALT+0224 (Lowercase Stressed A)
è   ALT+0232 (Lowercase Stressed Open E)
é   ALT+0233 (Lowercase Stressed Closed E)
ì   ALT+0236 (Lowercase Stressed I written with grave accent)
í   ALT+0237 (Lowercase Stressed I written with acute accent)
ò   ALT+0242 (Lowercase Stressed Open O)
ó   ALT+0243 (Lowercase Stressed Closed O)
ù   ALT+0249 (Lowercase Stressed U written with grave accent)
ú   ALT+0250 (Lowercase Stressed U written with acute accent)
î   ALT+0238 (Lowercase (Ending Truncated Stressed) I with circumflex)

º   ALT+0186 (Masculine Ordinal)
ª   ALT+0170 (Feminine Ordinal)
«   ALT+0171 (Left Angle Quote)
»   ALT+0187 (Right Angle Quote)
€   ALT+0128 (Euro Currency Symbol)
£   ALT+0163 (Old Italian Lira Currency Symbol (Same as UK Pound Currency Symbol))
```

The Euro (`€`) symbol can also be inserted via the `AltGr+e` and `AltGr+5` keyboard combinations.

In Microsoft Word as well as in LibreOffice, when lowercase letters such as `è` are inserted at the beginning of a sentence the software automatically converts them to uppercase letters such as `È`. In both software products it is also possible to switch between title case, all caps, and lowercase, by highlighting the given text and entering the `SHIFT+F3` key combination. This significantly reduces the need for being able to enter uppercase letters with diacritics directly via the keyboard when using these software products.

It is also possible to produce these characters inside other software products including text editors by installing [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) and using it to assign special characters to unused keyboard combinations (e.g. combinations resulting from pressing the `AltGr` key in combination with other keys, given that `AltGr` is present on Italian keyboard but on Windows most of such combinations do not output any characters by default).

Reagards.

---

UPDATE:

In support of one of the given responses which mentions that Italians will often append a diacritic to a vowel rather than including both as part of the same character when conventient to do so I have taken a few pictures in an Italian supermarket where two items have been spelled out using (a) an appended apostrophe/quote character acting as a  grave accent and (b) an appended backquote acting as an acute accent:

[image]

[image]

I have also found the following samples of written text in Italy:

[image]

In the above picture the word being spelled out is `qualità`, but IMHO given that all letters are in uppercase, in order to make the text stand out even more, the person who wrote the sign decided to append an apostrophe at the end instead of a grave accent, so there are also marketing reasons.

Another example is the name of the chain of Italian supermarkets Alí (which has now been operating in the country for at least thirty years) and has its last vowel spelled with an acute accent (although, as mentioned, it is possible to use this as less common alternative to the grave accent on written *i* and *u* vowels appearing at the end of the word):

[image]

---

Finally, there is one finer point to mention. The people who came up with the Unicode standard, which is a very well known standard in the computer world and can be used to represent all characters, diacritics, etc... in every language in the world, has noticed that if Unicode is to truly represent languages internationally then the forward quote (') and backquote (`) found on all standard US ASCII keyboards (and where the forward quote has also been always also used as an apostrophe when composing English plaintext) need to be considered as separate characters from the apostrophe, grave accent, and acute accent, so much so that these five entities have received their own Unicode encodings (as standalone diacritics), with three types of double quotes (left, right, and neutral) also receiving their own characters:

```
U+0022  QUOTATION MARK  "
U+0027  APOSTROPHE  '
U+0060  GRAVE ACCENT    `
U+00B4  ACUTE ACCENT    ´
U+2018  LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK  ‘
U+2019  RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK ’
U+201C  LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK  “
U+201D  RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK ”
U+0302  COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT ^
```

To type the above Unicode characters on Windows, hold down the `Alt` key, hit the `+ on the numeric keypad` key, then type the `hexadecimal digits` (e.g. 201c), then `release the Alt key`.

If you simply cut and paste these Unicode characters, you will see that they are all different. So, my guess is, one could write the more proper variants:

- à, è, é, ì (which in some texts appears consistently as í), ò, ó, ù (which in some texts appears consistently as ú)

or, alternatively, especially in those cases where for marketing purposes one may want the letters to stand out:

- a` , e` , e´ , i` (or i´), o`, o´, u` (or u´)

and the latter form would not be entirely wrong, since, technically, the appended diacritics are grave and acute accents and not apostrophes (although I do admittedly think this would indeed look somewhat funny inside proper printed texts)!

---

Although my original question had to do with the use of Italian hardware keyboards on Windows, for completeness, it is also worth mentioning that on Windows users of US hardware keyboards can easily add support for entering Italian vowels with diacritics adding a `US International` keyboard in Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Keyboards and Languages -> Change Keyboards... -> Add... -> English (United States) -> Keyboard -> Check *US - International* -> Apply -> OK, and the keyboards can then be switched from the switcher in the lower-right hand side of the windows taskbar. With this keyboard one can type:

- Apostrophe (') then uppercase or lowercase vowel to produce a vowel with grave accent.
- Backquote (`) then uppercase or lowercase vowel to produce a vowel with acute accent.
- Apostrophe or backquote, then SPACE or any other character to produce an apostrophe or backquote on its own.

Regards.

Comment: About your photos: the second is actually an error for sure (illiterate employee?), the first instead could not be. There are some words that actually sounds like if they need a diacritic sign but indeed they need an apostrophe. Example: "po'" common abbreviation of "poco" needs the ' but sounds like "pò", this happens often with names like "tacle'". OT ended.

Comment: When you say *the first instead could not be*, the Italian meaning of the English *the first could not be* is *è impossibile che il primo lo sia*, whereas if you meant to say *il primo invece non poteva esserlo* then in English you should say *on the other hand the first one couldn't have been a mistake*. Which one of these are you trying to say? Anyways, I have updated my post, please leave another comment with some more details if you wish to clarify the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Also, since in the comment above you've spelled *tacle'* with an apostrophe, you seem to be suggesting that *tacle'* is a contraction of some longer word, just like *po'* is a contraction of the longer word *poco*. So, what is *tacle'* an abbreviation of? To me, it sounds like it might be a loan word from French, but I could be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: "the first instead could not be" -> "might not be", in italian: "Potrebbe non esserlo". Sorry, I'm studying a third Language and I get confused easily.

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help as well. Regards.

Comment: I'm suggesting that "tacle'" might actually be a surname (maybe the farmer). In Italy there are some surnames that lies in the limbo of accent or apostrophe; I personally know a guy whose surname ends in "..olò" and another "...ale'".

Comment: Interesting, it could indeed be as you say. For completeness, as far as the word `taclè` is concerned (I've also found this word spelled out without diacritics as simply `tacle` on the Internet in some places and this may well be for the very reason you mention), this word seems to be used in Italy to refer to a cross-breed between oranges of a specific breed and clementines. Regards.

Answer (score 5):

Windows: I guess there's only one way to do it (corrections are welcome): ALT+Numerical keyboard combination. For example È is ALT+0200.
Since the moment there are very few cases that requires diactritics uppercase and È is the most common, learning the combination will do the job easily even if most people will write: "E'". Programs like Word should correct it automatically (Writer from Libre Office does), while if you use other editors you should check it. If you're writing a web page, there's a code: `&Egrave;` (È) or `&Eacute;` (É) that you should use always anyway for compatibility.

Mac users have a combination that actually I can't remember (just open virtual keyboard).

Linux is an alien world to me, so I don't know.

Comment: The fact that Word and LibreOffice automatically convert these characters is quite useful, making ALT codes mostly necessary only when one needs to insert a word all of whose letters are uppercase, as could be needed when entering the title of a book or something similar. Thanks.

Comment: On a mac (UK keyboard) one keeps pressed E or SHIFT-E and various accent options pop up.

Comment: On Ubuntu (Linux) caps lock works also on èéàò etc.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but Word might have an autocapitalizer somewhere. Something like a function that will make all your text uppercase and viceversa. Check it.

Comment: @Skliwz, from your comment it appears that Mac keyboards work the same as Android keyboards in this regard.

Comment: @IssamTP, yes Word does indeed have an autocapitalizer. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing the point here, but if you set your language to US International, and I assume various others, this is easy.

Apostrophe (') then shift-E produces É.

Backquote (`) then shift-E produces È.

Various other combinations are available. I don't know about using the Italian language profile itself.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have a US keyboard but I know the positions of keys on such keyboard by heart, and so I've tried the US International keyboard out of curiosity. So, how would you enter something like \`E\` (including the backquotes) on such keyboard? Thanks.

Comment: To get the literal key output instead of them serving as a modifier, you press it and then press something that isn't a vowel. Additionally, following them with a space doesn't insert a space. So e.g. backquote-then-space produces `. Make sense?

Comment: Also, and this will vary based on your settings (e.g. http://i60.tinypic.com/2yv2s0x.png ), you can switch between your usual keyboard and US International with a key combination. I use Ctrl-Shift, as you can see. This means you can effectively switch on easy access to accents, and then quickly go back to having your keyboard respond as per the actual keys.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this. As a matter of fact I have several languages configured, and even make use of multiple keyboards for some of these languages and use them as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Italian) says

> When using Microsoft Windows, the standard Italian keyboard layout
>   does not allow one to write 100% correct Italian language, since it
>   lacks capital accented vowels, and in particular the È key. The common
>   workaround is writing E' (E followed by an apostrophe) instead, or
>   relying on the auto-correction feature of several word processors when
>   available.

As you seem to be interested in writing in Italian with that already has a different set of characters written on it, I recommend you to use a different layout where you have dead keys for diacritis, such as a Portuguese or Spanish layout.

PS: I cannot understand the reason, either. **Specially** when already providing an `Alt Gr` key with little use. *(On Linux you will probably find many* undocumented *`Alt Gr` combinations adding extra characters).*

Comment: Writing “E'” for “È” isn't a workaround, by any definition of “workaround”: is a different thing, and a wrong one.

Comment: @DaG Technical correctness isn't always proportional with popularity of usage :)

Comment: As to undocumented Alt Gr combinations on Linux -- I'm not sure if it counts as "documentation", but on Ubuntu you can select "Keyboard layout chart" from the keyboard menu and see a graphical map of the keyboard showing characters available with various combinations of Alt Gr and Shift. On the Italian layout every possible combination is used for something, with Alt Gr combinations usually reserved for less common characters like ħ, ⅜, and ð.

Answer (score 3):

When using Linux you may use [Compose Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) and map the right control, for example, to be the Compose key. This can be done under Keyboard/Keymapping settings tool of your Desktop Manager. Then you'll be able to use several default mappings as well as create your own set of key mapping. I was not able to use Compose Keys on OS/X although they work well on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, I have found that many people simply resort to `E'` for `È`/`É`, `A'` for `À`, and so on. However, there are also some OS-specific tricks:

**Windows**: there is no easy way. Some may employ Alt combinations (just like `Alt+125` prints `}`, there are Alt combinations for uppercase accented letters), some may use `charmap`, some may use word processors which auto-capitalize the first letter of sentences.

**Mac**: if you long-press a vowel, a menu appears, asking which letter to enter (eg. long-pressing `E` gives `È`, `É`, and possibly other characters). Alternatively, one may use the Character Map.

**Linux**, specifically Ubuntu: pressing `è` with Caps Lock on prints `È`, `é` (`Shift+è`) prints `É`, and so on.

Some also use the US International keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

To enter diacritics in Windows I would suggest [this keyboard layout](https://code.google.com/p/usialtgr/). Certainly, you can create a "layout of your dream" :) with [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). However it's a bit boring, so I'd stay with the first option (which essentially is the product of such a generator).

With this layout you could enter lowercase diacritics with `<right-alt>+<base_letter>` and uppercase with `<right-alt>+<shift>+<base letter>`. I use this layout when I write Spanish (huh, ¡Español! :) or e.g. Ágil and found it the most conventient solution for Windows, especially when you need to do a lot of programmings, and thus have to enter "strings" or 'c'haracters all the time.

In Linux which is my primary desktop OS, I use the following xkb settings:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(altgr-intl)+ru(ruu):2+inet(evdev)+altwin(left_meta_win)+group(lctrl_lshift_toggle)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)+keypad(pointerkeys)+level3(caps_switch)"        };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)"     };
};
```

This allows me to write English with all ' (quotes), " (double-quotes), and ` (backticks) as usual plus diacritics like á or ¡ by pressing `<CapsLock>+<base_letter>` (it's more convenient than `<alt>+<base_letter>`, because `<alt>+<letter>` are often used for shortcuts). Also I have a completely separate layout for Cyrillic (Russian + sometimes Ukrainian), turned on and off by left `<ctrl>+<shift>`

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use the US-International layout, which has the benefit of using the Alt-Gr key to negate the need to switch between different keyboard layouts. It works correctly with Caps Lock and with shift (the letters are correctly converted to their uppercase equivalents). It also has the added advantage of not requiring you to learn new layouts when learning a new language with diacritics such as German or Spanish.

An example is given at [this website](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/italian.html):

Additional benefits of US-International are that it can type non-standard Latin characters in multiple languages (eg Spanish ñ, Nordic å, æ and ø, Old English þ, ð, German ä,ü,ö).

A drawback is the "dead key" feature of US-International, which is especially grating for programmers, who use the dead keys frequently in programming. To prevent this, you can download the custom keyboard layout [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/disable-dead-keys-for-us-international-keyboard/1de44160-83d9-4cd8-9eb3-e6b06b8604a4) which disables dead keys.

Answer (score 1):

French here. We have accents as well, and academic rules state that you don't have to put accents on uppercase letters.
While handwriting, it can be diffidult to put accents, as it was on machine typing.
The exception was likely made due to the uselessness of accents on first-letter uppercase.

However, you have several ways to put accents. First is to let your word processor auto-upper the letter. Then you have the ctrl-shift-u shortcut. And finally, the alt codes.

Comment: On my version of Word CTRL+SHIFT+U is the same as CTRL+U and simply makes the text appear in bold. Where have you used that keyboard combination?

Comment: I don't know French very well, but in Italian there are definite cases where you have to use upper-case accented letters, e.g. "È sera."

Answer (score 1):

With an Italian keyboard, if you press alt+9, you get a combination that lets you insert a grave accent over any vowel (even uppercase); alt+8 gives you the acute accent. But most people don't bother; they just put an apostrophe after the uppercase vowel (especially E', to distinguish it from the conjunction.

Comment: I have an Italian keyboard and am running Windows 7. The 'Alt+8' and 'Alt+9' keys you mention don't produce any characters at all, and I couldn't find any information like that on the Internet. Excatly what keyboard and operating system are you using and do you have any custom keystroke combination output configured for your keyboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Spanish International keyboard for Windows allows both types of accents by either pressing the tilde key (and releasing) for àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ or holding down the Alt key and the appropriate keys to produce áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ. I find this is the simplest method for Italian and Spanish.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to handle this problem is use the Spanish (Spain) keyboard instead of the Italian keyboard.  The Brazilian (Brazil ABNT) keyboard also works, but its question mark is in a strange place (right-alt w, go figure!) as well as some other quirks.  The Spanish keyboard is the most versatile and allows you to type all vowels both lowercase and uppercase with either of the two accent marks: áéíóú, àèìòù, ÁÉÍÓÚ, ÀÈÌÒÙ.  The only drawback is that for each letter w/ accent compound symbol you have to hit two keys, one after the other.  The first key you hit is the desired accent mark (´ which is where the usual English keyboard apostrophe is, and the ` which is just above the apostrophe and the same key as the English [ key).  These are "dead" keys in that you will see nothing appear UNTIL you next hit the vowel you want, which is entered either lowercase or uppercase (with the normal shift key at the same time).  Then you will see the combined character all of which I have typed above.  The Spanish keyboard has the benefits of also allowing many other characters such as the upside down ¿ and upside down ¡ as well as ç and allows you to put a ¨ over any vowel such as äëïöü.  These are also made with 2 keystrokes: the ¨ on the double quote key which is also "dead," followed by the vowel and then the compound symbol appears.  I use the Spanish (Spain) keyboard when I type in both Spanish and Italian and it works great.